# Getting CRC-32 over STM32 flash and consistency with other CRC-32 tools

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, crc

I'm moving my STM32F1xx project to a solution with a bootloader.
Part of this is that I want to be able to compute a CRC value over the existing bootloader and application flash ranges to compare existing and possible upload candidates.

Using a simple implementation on the STM32 which just does the following steps:

- Enable CRC periperal
- Reset the peripheral CRC value (sets to 0xFFFFFFFF)
- Iterate over flash range (in this case 0x08000000 to 0x08020000) passing values to CRC peripheral
- Return CRC peripheral output

```
uint32_t get_crc(void) {
    RCC->AHBENR |= RCC_AHBENR_CRCEN;
    CRC->CR |= CRC_CR_RESET;

    for(uint32_t *n = (uint32_t *)FLASH_BASE; n < (uint32_t *)(FLASH_BANK1_END + 1u); n ++) {
        CRC->DR = *n;
    }

    return CRC->DR;
}
```

The value I get from this is **0x0deddeb3**.

To compare this value with something I am running the .bin file through two tools.

The value I get from npm's [crc-32](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crc-32) is **0x776b0ea2**

The value I get from a [zip file's](https://superuser.com/questions/1434718/any-built-in-checksum-utility-for-windows-10-using-crc-32) CRC-32 is **also 0x776b0ea2**

What could be causing this? Is there a difference between iterating over the entire flash range and the contents of the bin file (smaller than entire flash range)? The polynomial used by the STM32 is 0x04c11db7 which seems to be fairly standard for a CRC-32. Would the zip tool and npm crc-32 be using a different polynomial?

I have also tried iterating over bytes and half-words as well as words on the STM32 in case the other tools used a different input format.

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36483334/make-crc-on-stm32-match-with-software-implementation) on here already, but I'm hoping to use a node-js solution because that is the platform my interface application is being developed on.

Comment: Translate the code in the answer to the similar question to javascript.

Comment: @mark-adler I have tried that but I still get different results. It must be how I'm iterating over the bin file vs the flash memory

Comment: Make sure you are using the "ethernet CRC32" and not some other one. There's at least 4 different polynomials and likely different initial checksum values, different invert/don't invert at the end etc. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check

Comment: You need to provide a short string, a good one is "123456789", and the correct CRC for that string.

Comment: @MarkAdler thanks. I definitely underestimated the task and just assumed I could jump in since I've worked with CRCs before, it turns out I have only worked with CRCs in a system that had already been very carefully designed by my colleagues

Comment: The [SRecord](http://srecord.sourceforge.net/) package tools have an input filter option for generating STM32 compatible CRCs.  See the description of the -STM32 option for [srec_input](http://srecord.sourceforge.net/man/man1/srec_input.html) for some ideas.

Comment: @kkrambo that's a great resource, thanks. It looks like the main issue is word vs byte-fed data and a slightly different polynomial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calculating CRCs is a mine field. Your question already has some points to look at:

> Is there a difference between iterating over the entire flash range and the contents of the bin file (smaller than entire flash range)?

Yes, of course.

> Would the zip tool and npm crc-32 be using a different polynomial?

The documentation will tell you. And I'm sure that you can use another polynomial with this tools by an option.

Anyway, these are the things to consider when calculating CRCs:

1. The amount of bytes (words, ...) to "sum up".
2. The contents of the flash not covered by the binary file, most probably all bits set to 1.
3. Width of the polynomial (in your case fixed to 32 bits).
4. Value of the polynomial.
5. Initial value for the register.
6. Whether the bits of each byte are reflected before being processed.
7. Whether the algorithm feeds input bytes through the register or xors them with a byte from one end and then straight into the table.
8. Whether the final register value should be reversed (as in reflected versions).
9. Value to XOR with the final register value.

The points 3 to the last are shamelessly copied from ["A PAINLESS GUIDE TO CRC ERROR DETECTION ALGORITHMS"](https://archive.org/stream/PainlessCRC/crc_v3.txt) that I suggest to read.

Comment: Following this answer and discussion with my colleagues, I'm going to dial it back. I'll work on getting the STM32 and other CRC tools to first provide the same answer for a single word, then an array of words, then work on the flash range. I'm going to accept this answer because it breaks down the variables the best and has good resources to continue with. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The polynomial is only one of several parameters that define a CRC. In this case the CRC is not reflected, whereas the standard zip CRC, using the same polynomial is reflected. Also that zip CRC is exclusive-or'ed with `0xffffffff` at the end, whereas yours isn't. They do both get initialized the same, which is with `0xffffffff`.